# UIPickerView not showing up

Tags: iphone, uiimage, ios6, uipickerview

I have a `UIPickerView` that wont show up when I run the app because I created it programmatically and I'm using a `UIImage` as a background for the app. How can I get it to show up ? I have tried

```
      [super.view sendSubviewToFront...];
```

and it still doesn't show up. Any idea why?

Comment: I made the UIImage in IB btw.

Comment: try  `[self.view sendSubviewToFront...];`

Comment: that didn't worth either

Comment: Have you added it to the view hierarchy?

Comment: Show Me the code itll be easier to identify...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont have my Mac rite now but ill give you the basic idea . What you should really do is after allocating both the image and the pickerview ; first `addSubView` the `UIImage` onto the `self.View` and then `addSubView` the `UIPickerView` on the `UIImage` like

```
[self.View addSubView:image];
[image addSubView:pickerView];
```

Any doubt let me know . Thanks .